# django REST framework error: cannot import name 'PaginationSerializer'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My django framework is throwing an error while importing 'PaginationSerializer'. Any idea what could have gone wrong? Please find below the line which throws the error. I am using django REST framework 3.1 release.

```
    from rest_framework.pagination import PaginationSerializer
```

Below is the error output.

```
    ImportError at /

    cannot import name 'PaginationSerializer'

    Request Method:     GET
    Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:3434/
    Django Version:     1.8.2
    Exception Type:     ImportError
    Exception Value:    cannot import name 'PaginationSerializer'
    Exception Location:     /home/djangoDevelopment/test.git/rest_peace/urls.py in <module>, line 9
    Python Executable:  /home/pulak/djangoDevelopment/django-test.git/djenv/bin/python
    Python Version:     3.4.3
```

Comment: Did you add `rest_framework` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings

Comment: Yes, of course. The other imports e.g. routers, serializers working fine!!

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: I am using REST framework version 3.1.

Comment: `PaginationSerializer` was removed in DRF 3.1 release.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`PaginationSerializer` was removed in DRF 3.1 release. The pagination API underwent a lot of changes, making it both easier to use, and more powerful.

Now, instead of using the `PaginationSerializer`, you need to override the `get_paginated_response()` function.

As per the [changes](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.1-announcement/#pagination) announced in DRF 3.1 in `Pagination` API:

> The`pagination_serializer_class` view attribute and
>   `DEFAULT_PAGINATION_SERIALIZER_CLASS` settings key **are no longer valid**.
>   The pagination API does not use serializers to determine the output
>   format, and you'll need to instead override the `get_paginated_response`
>   method on a pagination class in order to specify how the output format
>   is controlled.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found what the issue is. Using REST framework v3.1 breaks the pagination. The issue is addressed in the following link. In case someone runs into this kind of trouble in future: [Django Rest Framework 3.1 breaks pagination.PaginationSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29128225/django-rest-framework-3-1-breaks-pagination-paginationserializer)